# Copy paste inside w3m command line browser in ubuntu server

Tags: server, w3m

After browsing any link using w3m browser, that comes by default with Ubuntu server, I am not able to do copy paste content of webpage.
I surf link using

```
w3m <link>
```

After surfing link, I pressed `Ctrl+Insert` but did not find any any copy paste option.
I have installed gpm, but it also not allow to copy.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a server, use `screen` which provides a mechanism to copy program output/display content independently. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22355072/2072269) provides a quick guide:

> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>,
> - arrows to get to the start of the URL
> - <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start selection
> - arrows to get to the end of the URL
> - <kbd>Enter</kbd> to end selection and push it into screen's buffer
> - paste it into a shell using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>

You should use `screen` (or `tmux`) for a lot of reasons if you're on a server. This is one of them.

Comment: Thanks, @muru. I will give try to it. But i want to copy the content of web page and paste it somewhere on server. Can it be done?

Comment: @rohinichaudhary if you want to save an entire web page, try curl or wget